# WPF/XAML - Use 'Style' to create tooltip with model element name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic, tooltip

We have a very complex questionnaire in WPF with 100s of controls.  Groups of controls are put together into UserControls to better organize sections. They are visible/collapsed based on a variety of factors.  This questionnaire changes quarterly due to vendor changes. We bind a data model to the datacontext.  The model property names match the database column name.

When the questionnaire goes to QA, they would like some easy way to relate a questionnaire control to a database column.  As part of their due diligence, they verify that the value in the database matches what they entered in the GUI.

My thought, was to add a tooltip (or similar mechanism) that would display the binding property.   We don't want the end user to see this, so we need to turn this dynamic tooltip on/off with a config setting.

I am trying to find an easy way to simply use reflection in a global <style>.  It would build the tooltip with the binding property name on all controls (enabled/disabled by a config option).  I thought maybe I could use a converter to do this, but I'm not able to figure out exactly how to make that work.

I want the tooltip to show 'VariableName1' or 'VariableName2' on controls (VariableName1/VariableName2 is the name of the database column).

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=VariableName1, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

or

```
<CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource Radio}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=VariableName2}"/>
```

I tried an approach like this, thinking that in the 'QATooltips' method, I could do reflection and build the tooltip.  But the converter never gets called.  So I have something wired up wrong.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:QATooltips x:Key="QATooltips" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ToolTip Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource QATooltips}}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by calling `GetBindingExpression` on the element in question, passing in the dependency property you're interested in. The name will be in the `ResolvedSourcePropertyName` property of the resulting expression.

The converter you're looking for is something like this:

```
public class BindingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value as FrameworkElement)?.GetBindingExpression(parameter as DependencyProperty)?.ResolvedSourcePropertyName;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Note how it's expecting the DP that you're interested in to be passed in as the command parameter, that way you don't have to create a separate converter type for each of your different binding types.

Back in your XAML you simply do this:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=PresentationFramework"

<Window.Resources>

    <local:BindingConverter x:Key="BindingConverter" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Converter={StaticResource BindingConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static controls:TextBlock.TextProperty}}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Converter={StaticResource BindingConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static controls:RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty}}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTextField}" />
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding MyBooleanField}" Content="Click Me" />
</StackPanel>
```

(BTW, the reason your original code didn't work is because the ToolTips aren't child elements of their "parent" control's visual tree, that's why you have to bind via PlacementTarget instead).

Comment: Wow.   I was able to get this to do EXACTLY what I wanted.  Thank you so much!